# Grant User only access to use SQL Admin (read only) without accessing SQL DB content?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, readonly

Our SQL administrator is currently ill and in the hospital however we have an upcoming security audit from the SQL cluster. Therefore we would like to grant the security auditor now read only access so that he can see all settings (primary which DB has which settings and which users are created). But the auditor shouldn´t have any rights to access DB content. Could that be performed? If yes how?

Comment: [link](https://chartio.com/docs/datasources/connections/details/sqluser) go through the link

Comment: @AMS thats exactly what I do NOT wish to perform. Via that way the user HAS read access to the DB content. If it contains finance data he is able to read them. So thats not a way I´m looking into. However thanks for checking the question.

Answer (score 0):

As Per my understanding you are looking for this solution where you want only definition access to user not the data reader operation access.

If this is the case then You can do it using `GRANT Schema Permissions (Transact-SQL)`

[image]

The VIEW DEFINITION permission lets a user see the metadata of the securable on which the permission is granted. However, VIEW DEFINITION permission does not confer access to the securable itself. For example, a user that is granted only VIEW DEFINITION permission on a table can see metadata related to the table in the sys.objects catalog view. However, without additional permissions such as SELECT or CONTROL, the user cannot read data from the table.

[For more details go through the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187940.aspx)

For grant access to different functionality of SQL Server you can go through the following link
[GRANT PERMISSION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)